# JavaScript is not executed when inserted in DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

EDIT: filter() was oviously wrong. Changed it to find(), however the problem remains.

This code works for me:

```
$('#content')
   .replaceWith($(
      '<div>
       <div id="content"> Hello <script type="text/javascript"> alert(123); </script>
       </div>
       </div>
      '));
```

But this does not:

```
$('#content')
   .replaceWith($(
      '<div>
       <div id="content"> Hello <script type="text/javascript"> alert(123); </script>
       </div>
       </div>
      ').find('#content'));
```

The only difference is that in the second example I want to filter only one part of the HTML and then insert that into the DOM.

Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT3: Added the solution as answer

Comment: are you executing this code using the `document.ready` callback?

Comment: try doing it separatedly

Comment: Do you get any errors or just not being inserted ?

Comment: check this link: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: What's even weirder is that in the first case after running the code and inspecting the DOM, the `script` element is nowhere to be found - even though the Javascript had executed properly... http://jsfiddle.net/QwJay/

Comment: I was writing an answer but it did not solve the problem... The interesting thing id that passing this HTML string to jQuery does not generate a jQuery object with *one* selected element, but **two**: The `div` with the other `div` as child, and the `script` element. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/gEEjV/1/ I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: jQuery always strips `<script>` elements out of content before adding the content to the DOM.  Generally it executes the scripts after updating the DOM with new content. It could be the case that with the call to ".filter()" the content has to be inserted into a doc fragment or something, the scripts may get lost before they're run.

Comment: It's around line 6357 of the unminified 1.7.1 code; it seems to append scripts found in newly-created fragments to the end of the jQuery element list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Felix! That pushed me into the right direction. And yes, ZiTAL, doing it seperately is the key.

Comment: Bergi: Sorry for being such a stackoverflow noob ^^
I now added the solution as answer and will mark it as accepted once I'm allowed to do so.

It also seems that I cannot upvote comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var newElements = $('<div><div id="content"><script>alert(123)</script></div></div>');
if (newElements.length > 1) {
  for (var i = 1; i < newElements.length; i++) {
    $('body').append(newElements[i]);
  }
}
$('#content').html(newElements.find('#content').html());
```

The reason is that creating the elements in the first call, sorts out all script tags and puts them in an array.

```
console.log($('<div><div id="content"><script>alert(123)</script></div></div>'));
```

Result:

```
[div, script]
```

Then obviously when applying .find() to that array the script tags are lost.